# Localization AsyncFileUpload(Ajax ControlToolkit)

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In my project I use asyncfileupload to upload files and I have one problem:

I'm from Russia and would like to localize this control to Russia language.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to localize AsyncFileUpload, not the AjaxFileUpload control?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will give you the best insight.
http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/11/23/multi-lingual-web-applications-using-asp-net-4.aspx